# Is there a difference between the address operator and a pointer in assembly?

Tags: c, assembly, x86, reverse-engineering, decompiling

does the compiler translate the address operator any different than a pointer?

I'm wondering because the decompiler sometimes shows me:

```
func_test(&a, &b[0x32*ebx])
```

which should be essentially the same as

```
func_test((_DWORD *)a,(_DWORD *)(b+0x32*ebx))
```

correct? I'm mildy confused by the arithmetic tbh.
Does it have any special meaning having it shown this way or is this just to read it easier?

Comment: The expressions involving `b` look equivalent, and the first one is simpler and more like LEA syntax.  But the expressions involving `a` aren't; you're now casting the value to a pointer, instead of taking the address.  This is more of a C question than asm.

Comment: Note that `&b[50 * ebx]` isn't something you can do in one LEA instruction; scale factors can only left-shift by 0..3 bits, not arbitrary multiply.  Although a single LEA can multiply by 5 with `lea eax, [ebx + ebx*4]`

Comment: @Peter Cordes is this limited due to 4 bytes would 86_64 limit be 8 bytes? also it's still unclear to me if both ways are translated exactly the same way to assembly and if the decompiler just chose this way of showing for optic reasons

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`&a` returns the address of `a`, while `(_DWORD *)a` forces the compiler to reinterpret the content of `a` as a pointer to a `_DWORD`. so the two expressions are fundamentally different.

It may be equivalent if `a` is an array of `_DWORD` (declared like `_DWORD a[A_LENGTH];`). In this case `&a` and `a` is essentially the same as `a` in pointer context degrades to a simple pointer, allthough the `_DWORD *` cast is redundant then.

The expression for `b` is equivalent.